# Is various UIgesture has precedence over touchbagan?

Tags: ios, ios7

I found when I have UIGesture, like UITapGesture, it always take precedence over the touchbegan methods etc.

Reading books, If setting "Delayed Begin", this should be true. But I don't set the "Delayed Begin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `touchesBegan:` is delivered both to the gesture recognizer and to the view. It isn't `touchesBegan:` that is delayed by default - it's `touchesEnded:`, meaning that the gesture recognizer holds onto this until it can decide whether to recognize its gesture or not (and this is especially important for a multitap gesture, because the first touch may end but the gesture might still recognize if there's a further tap).

Comment: And see my full discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizer_and_view